# How to use RxJS fromEvent() with HammerJS in strict mode

Tags: javascript, rxjs, hammer.js

The following code gives an error in typescript strict mode:

```
       const hammerTap = new Hammer(nativeElement, 
        {
            recognizers: [
                [Hammer.Tap, { taps: 4 }]
            ]
        });

        const tap$ = fromEvent(hammerTap, 'tap').pipe(share());
```

> Argument of type 'HammerManager' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'FromEventTarget<{}>'.   Type 'HammerManager' is not assignable
>   to type 'JQueryStyleEventEmitter'.
>       Types of property 'on' are incompatible.
>         Type '(events: string, handler: HammerListener) => void' is not assignable to type '(eventName: string, handler: Function) => void'.
>           Types of parameters 'handler' and 'handler' are incompatible.
>             Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'HammerListener'.
>               Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(event: HammerInput): void'.

Answer (score 1):

The problem would only be truly fixable in `@types/hammerjs`, but you can do this:

```
const tap$ = fromEvent(<JQueryStyleEventEmitter> <unknown> hammerTap, 'tap').pipe(share());
```

or

```
const tap$ = fromEvent(hammerTap as unknown as JQueryStyleEventEmitter, 'tap').pipe(share());
```

`JQueryStyleEventEmitter` is defined as the following, and is part of RxJS, so don't worry - you're not including JQuery in any way shape or form.

```
export interface JQueryStyleEventEmitter {
    on: (eventName: string, handler: Function) => void;
    off: (eventName: string, handler: Function) => void;
}
```

You can also add `<HammerInput>` as a generic parameter to `fromEvent`, so the events coming back to you are of the correct type.

```
const panUnfilteredRaw$ = fromEvent<HammerInput>(hammerPan as unknown as JQueryStyleEventEmitter, 'panstart panmove panend').pipe(share());
```